# OS X Different Docks For Different Desktops

Tags: macos, desktop, dock

Is there anyway or is there any software out there that will allow me to have a different dock for each desktop...

Meaning, I would like to only see the windows open on that desktop for that dock...

Any info is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this was already answered [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56784/different-desktop-with-different-dock).

In short: you can't have different docks - sorry about that.

Comment: I would like to give you both the bounty, if I do nothing, will that happen?

Comment: If you do nothing, I get half of the bounty. What do you mean by "Both"? I saw only one bounty.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a complete answer :

The Dock is a stand-alone application in dependant of Spaces/Mission Control. As you cannot have different Desktop (yes you have spaces but it always `/Desktop` that is shown with sometimes a different background), you cannot change the docks behaviour.

Apple did not make the dock very customisable and beside the UI it did not change a lot since the first OSX was released.