# Is there a way to set unique applications in the Dock per Desktop in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, desktop, dock

I have many applications open and all of them show up in the task bar.  However I only use a handful per desktop screen.

I want to find a way to only display applications that are active for that desktop.

For Windows I have been using [UltraMon](https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/smart_taskbar.asp) that allows exactly this type of functionality.

I’m surprised no one has created anything similar to that for Mac OS X.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Thank you, I figured as much.  I doubt people will search my question to answer it.  Is there a friendly way to bump this post?

Comment: Perfect, I appreciate the help.  Looks like i'll have to build up some rep.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [OS X Different Docks For Different Desktops](http://superuser.com/questions/597266/os-x-different-docks-for-different-desktops), where unfortunately the answer is "not possible". Maybe some OSX replacement dock will be the solution, but product recommendations are out of bounds on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the official answer right now is that there is no answer.  I was hoping things have changed for OSX over the past few years but basic functionality that's been with Windows since XP doesn't quite exist yet for OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Check this program: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/27841/dock-spaces

It seems that is what you need